# Open New Tab after reload page

Tags: jquery

I have problem with open new tab. Let say i have list a bunch barcode on datatable, and i must selected which one i need to scan or create pdf. After i selected i push button for open new tab (create pdf). But my problem is, it isn't open new tab just reload page on current page. Here my code

```
$('#btnscanbar').on('click', function() {
            var cekdata = $(this).attr('data-cek');
            var judul = $(this).attr('data-target');
            var target2 = $('#btnsearch').attr('data-target');
            var dataString = "judul=" + cekdata;        
            var fFactory = $("#fFactory").val();
            var fmachine = $("#fmachine").val();
            var fbrand = $("#fbrand").val();
            $.ajax
            ({
                type: "post",
                url:  host+ "AMS/ajax",
                data: dataString,
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                success: function(json_data)
                {
                    if(json_data.total==0)
                    {
                        swal("Please select barcode wanna scan", "warning");
                    }
                    else
                    {


                        window.open(url+'pdf?judul=' + judul + '&fFactory=' + fFactory +'&fmachine=' + fmachine +'&fbrand=' + fbrand, '_blank')                     
                        //reload current page
                        location.reload();
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

Any solution?? I need open new tab and reload page but not working with that code.

UPDATE :
I found solution, i'm using alert before open new tab, here the code i'm usingit

```
swal({ 
                            title: "Ready for Scan",
                            text: "Your Barcode succesed being scan, press OK to see",
                            type: "success",
                            confirmButtonText: "Ok",
                        }).then(function(){ 
                            window.open(url+'pdf?judul=' + judul + '&fFactory=' + fFactory +'&fmachine=' + fmachine +'&fbrand=' + fbrand, '_blank')                     
                            window.location.reload();
                        });
```

Comment: what is it you want to do? open the tab pr reload the page?

Comment: anything i wanna open new tab and reload current page at same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution on these one

On these code

```
 window.open(url+'pdf?judul=' + judul + '&fFactory=' + fFactory +'&fmachine=' + fmachine +'&fbrand=' + fbrand, '_blank')                     
                    //reload current page
                    location.reload();
```

I'm changed into

```
swal({ 
                            title: "Ready for Scan",
                            text: "Your Barcode succesed being scan, press OK to see",
                            type: "success",
                            confirmButtonText: "Ok",
                        }).then(function(){ 
                            window.open(url+'pdf?judul=' + judul + '&fFactory=' + fFactory +'&fmachine=' + fmachine +'&fbrand=' + fbrand, '_blank')                     
                            window.location.reload();
                        });
```

And it work perfectly, hope if someone get problem like me, use these code. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's my solution. You can refer it. Hope to help, my friend :))

```
<body>
    <form id="myForm">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
        <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
      </div>
      <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    </form>
 </body>   

<script>
    function myFunction() {
       //for open a new tab
       let win =  window.open("https://www.w3schools.com", "_blank");
       win.focus();
       //document.getElementById("myForm").reset();            
       location.reload(true); //Reloads the current page from the server 
    }   
</script>
```

Comment: well is working on my computer but not working on another computer. And i edit my problem. Cause my problem is sloved.

Comment: @Wolfzmus: Well played, my friend :))

Comment: Tq and tq for your answer :)